# Hangman game same letter validation javascript only

Tags: javascript

I need help with my `hangman game`, how do I stop lives going down if players guess repeated letter before, as for now if I run it and player guesses the same letter, it will output that he have already made this guess but the lives is dropping too. Also if players keep input the same correct letter, it will output that he have already made this guesses but it will say he won after inputting the same letter 4-5 times.

1st error: `lives dropping even if players use letter that is guessed before`

2nd error: `players input the same correct letter guessed and game will say he won after inputting 4-5 times`

**Code**

```
guesses = [];

// Show player their progress | .join returned answer as a string
while (remainingLetters > 0 && lives > 0) {
    (answerArray.join(""));

    guess = readline.question(name+"'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ");
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    //if guess is more than 1 letter or no letter, alert player to guess 1 letter only
    if (guess.length !== 1) {
        console.log("Please enter 1 letter only.");
    }

    //if valid guess
    else {
        correctGuess = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < Word.length; j++) {
            if (Word[j] == guess) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
                correctGuess = 1;
            }
        }

        if (correctGuess == 1) {
                console.log("\nGood job! "+guess+" is one of the letters!\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray)+"\n");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets)+"\n");
        } else {
            lives -= 1;
            console.log("\nSorry. "+guess+" is not a part of the word.\n");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray)+"\n");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets)+"\n");
            console.log("You have "+lives+" lives remaining.\n");
        }
        
        if (guesses.includes(guess)) {
            console.log("You have already made this guess, please try another letter!\n");
        } else {
            guesses.push(guess)
        }
    }

    if (remainingLetters == 0) {
        console.log("Congratulation! You managed to guess the word!\n");
        break;
    }
    
    if (lives == 0) {
        console.log("Game Over... You failed to guess the word. The word is "+Word+".\n")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `else` for `valid guess` move your entire code inside `else` of `if (guesses.includes(guess)) {`. It will solve both of your issues.

```js
// Show player their progress | .join returned answer as a string
while (remainingLetters > 0 && lives > 0) {
  (answerArray.join(""));

  guess = readline.question(name + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ");
  guess = guess.toUpperCase();

  //if guess is more than 1 letter or no letter, alert player to guess 1 letter only
  if (guess.length !== 1) {
    console.log("Please enter 1 letter only.");
  }

  //if valid guess
  else {
    if (guesses.includes(guess)) {
      console.log("You have already made this guess, please try another letter!\n");
    } else {
      guesses.push(guess);
      correctGuess = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < Word.length; j++) {
        if (Word[j] == guess) {
          answerArray[j] = guess;
          remainingLetters--;
          correctGuess = 1;
        }
      }

      if (correctGuess == 1) {
        console.log("\nGood job! " + guess + " is one of the letters!\n");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
      } else {
        lives -= 1;
        console.log("\nSorry. " + guess + " is not a part of the word.\n");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
        console.log("You have " + lives + " lives remaining.\n");
      }
    }
  }

  if (remainingLetters == 0) {
    console.log("Congratulation! You managed to guess the word!\n");
    break;
  }
  
  if (lives == 0) {
    console.log("Game Over... You failed to guess the word. The word is " + Word + ".\n")
  }

}
```